# Ruby on rails attributes validations, methods in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, attributes

I have model Project and validates:

```
validates_presence_of :name, :position, :tel
```

Project also has another attributes, such as :flag.
I want to do so: 
if you enter :name, :position, :tel, then :flag = true, 
if one of these attributes are not specified, then :flag = false.

How can I make it and where? In model?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have that validation declared, the model won't even save unless the user enters all three, so setting flag to false is moot.

That being said, if you want to set an attribute at save time based on the values of other attributes, you can use one of the [callback hooks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) such as before_save.

```
class Project << ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_flag

  protected

  def set_flag
    self.flag = (self.name.blank? || self.position.blank? || self.tel.blank?) ? false : true
  end
end
```

Comment: And then you can set a validation on the flag... :)

Comment: Thanks, good! But If if delete validation for :tel, :name and :postion and make blank for example :tel attribute why your method not work? how can I fix it for model without validation?

Comment: Well, what is your goal - what's the purpose of the flag? Why would you remove the validations, if they are valid requirements? If you just want to know if the model is valid or not pre-save, there are better ways.

Comment: @Prychev, what do you mean when you say that the method doesn't work? Are you saying that flag is not being set? Can you post some of your code please?